# Getting nil Array of Follower back when performing asynchronous request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, frameworks, twitter

I am doing a Twitter App using the Twitter iOS 5 Framwork and it works quite well.
I am searching for all available TwitterAccounts on the device and load them into a tableview to display them. If the user touches on a account the next view is loaded and all followers are requested via the REST API and loaded into a array to parse each name and photo using the REST API. The problem is, the request isn't asynchronous and I am first getting a nil array and then getting the response of the API.

The requestMethod is the following:

```
__block NSArray *responseArray;

NSURL *tweetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json"];

NSString *username = [[[self getAvailableTwitterAccounts] objectAtIndex:user] username];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                                   initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-1", username, @"1", nil]
                                   forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cursor", @"username", @"stringify_ids" ,nil]];

//Build request
TWRequest *getFollowerRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:tweetURL 
                                                    parameters:parameters
                                                    requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

[getFollowerRequest setAccount:[[self getAvailableTwitterAccounts] objectAtIndex:user]];
[getFollowerRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
        responseArray = [response objectForKey:@"ids"];
        NSLog(@"responseArray %@ for user: %@",responseArray,username);
  });  
}];

return responseArray;
}
```

and the loading process:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   

followerIDArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NBNTwitterConnect sharedTwitterConnect] getFollowerIDsForUser:userID]];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self initDisplayArray];
}

-(void)initDisplayArray{

NSLog(@"followerIDArray: %@",followerIDArray);

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(arrayDidFinishedLoading:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)arrayDidFinishedLoading:(NSArray *)array{

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and the Output:

```
followerIDArray: (
)
2011-12-03 21:43:33.305 NBNTwitterChat[1858:10403] responseArray (
3840,
14064174,
281136865,
224987906
) for user:xyz
```

Can anyone assist me with that? I searched the whole web and I need to use the TWRequest method and not the asihttprequest or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'd say that it **is** asynchronous, which is causing the problem.

`-[TWRequest performRequestWithHandler:]` is an asynchronous method that will return instantly. You cannot return `responseArray` like you do, since it won't be filled before leaving the function.

You will have to write asynchronous code, or you will have to use `-[TWRequest signedURLRequest]` and do a synchronous request.